# Under what conditions is an input submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

When submitting a form, what inputs are submitted?

As an example:

1. [disabled inputs are not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted)...
2. [inputs wihtout a name attribute are not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472017/are-input-fields-without-a-name-attribute-submitted-to-the-server)...

I am looking for a more comprehensive/official document which explains what inputs are submitted?

Comment: Those are the two scenarios I know of. This post might have useful information for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submitted

Comment: Thanks, it's actually the same link in the question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a range of conditions.

The control's form owner must be the form being submitted and none of the following are true:

> - The field element has a datalist element ancestor.
> - The field element is disabled.
> - The field element is a button but it is not submitter.
> - The field element is an input element whose type attribute is in the Checkbox state and whose checkedness is false.
> - The field element is an input element whose type attribute is in the Radio Button state and whose checkedness is false.
> - The field element is an object element that is not using a plugin.

and a name must be established.

Details are in the HTML5 spec at [4.10.21.4 Constructing the entry list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-form-data-set)

Answer (score 2):

As W3 document (https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) said:

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
> - If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is
>   successful.
> - All "on" checkboxes may be successful.
> - For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio
>   button may be successful.
> - For menus, the control name is provided by a SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only selected options may be successful. When no options are selected, the control is not successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the server when the form is submitted.
> - The current value of a file select is a list of one or more file names. Upon submission of the form, the contents of each file are submitted with the rest of the form data. The file contents are packaged according to the form's content type.
> - The current value of an object control is determined by the object's implementation.

More details in the document.