# How to deal with input-text in a text area that is not submitted and other problems

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a Dockerised container application that is a student grade checker. I need to connect this application to a running SQL container. I have it connected successfully but I am running into issues with how to deal with the input data.

Here is where the input data is submitted:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="sgc">
    <div id="logo">
        Student Grade Checker App
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea class="display-input" id="input-text" rows="5" cols="35" required minlength="2" placeholder="Enter the module names and marks separated by comma [put each module in a new line]" value="">Enter the module names and marks separated by comma [put each module in a new line]</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea class="display-output" id="output-text" rows="5" cols="35" readonly=1 placeholder="Results here..." value="">
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="sgcbutton-active" onclick="verify();getTotal();">Total Marks</button>
    </div>
    <div>
```

The `textarea id="input-text"` is where I want to take the information from to enter into my database, however the information is not submitted anywhere until other microservices are called such as `getTotal`.

Here is the PHP that I have so far:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected to MySQL successfully!";

"input_text = document.getElementById('input-text').value";

$ModuleMarks = $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['input_text']);

echo $ModuleMarks;

$insertsql = "INSERT INTO Module_Marks (Module) VALUES('$ModuleMarks')";

$result = $conn->query($insertsql);

if (!$result) {

echo $conn->error;

?>
```

I am getting "Connected to MySQL successfully!" returned so I believe my database connection is ok.

I am getting an error output:
`call to a member function real_escape_string() on Boolean.`

but my first question is help with how to deal with the input text.

Thanks

Comment: I think you will discover that `$conn` is boolean `false` and not an object. You can use `mysqli_connect_error()` to see what the problem was.

Comment: Your `<textarea>` field needs a `name` attribute. See [Are <input> fields without a name attribute submitted to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472017/are-input-fields-without-a-name-attribute-submitted-to-the-server)